# Fixed против Sticky

Tags: css, position, fixed

Структура кода на [сайте](http://workout.korets.in.ua/xbolt/catalog.html) сейчас выглядит так:

```
<header></header>
<div class="filterBar"></div>
<что-то></еще>
<footer></footer>
```

В стилях header и .filterBar задано свойство **position: sticky;**
Что делает их «липкими» и самое главное весь последующий контент не плывет под них.
По ряду обстоятельств оказалось, что *sticky* мне не подходит и нужно заменить 
свойство *position* header и .filterBar на **position: fixed;**
И все вроде бы хорошо, но следующие блоки заплывают под них.
Как сделать, чтобы контент не заплывал под блоки с **position: fixed;** ?!

*(Прим.: на первой картинке заплывает)*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*(Прим.: на второй - так как нужно с отступами)*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для следующего элемента задайте `margin-top`, указав значением высоту блока, который помечен `fixed`.

Или для `body` можно то же самое сделать.

Comment: Это сработает, но у меня не на всех страницах есть блок .filterBar - прийдется уникально под каждую подстраиваться

Comment: @KobetsMatviy да, придётся подстраиваться

Comment: @KobetsMatviy, если ответ помог, просьба пометить решением

Comment: @hisbvdis Конечно. Если в течении суток MSDN не обновит свои стандарты, то отмечу (:
На самом деле думал, что есть более мудреной вариант